# After disable still shows all fields in user registration Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I have created new user profile plugin and installed it. I can see there are options to control showing fields on front end edit section and back-end forms from the admin.

But it still shows all fields in registration page after disable few fields. Other sections works fine. Is there any mistake I have done here?

Thanks.

Comment: Which fields exactly it still shows?

Comment: What fields are still showing?  How about a screen shot of your settings and what you're seeing rendered?

Comment: No fields can be disabled from the back-end. After disable fields still shows those fields.